# Cannot create entry when Entry Type has Title field hidden

Tags: entries

I have created an Entry Type with the "Show the Title field" option not checked.

When creating an entry of this type, I am given a generic "Couldn't save entry" error message.

Looking in craft.log, I see the Title field is failing validation.

```
2015/08/18 18:07:29 [trace] [system.CModule] Loading "templates" application component
in /Users/Sites/craft-test/web/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php (584)
in /Users/Sites/craft-test/web/craft/app/services/EntriesService.php (157)
in /Users/Sites/craft-test/web/craft/app/controllers/EntriesController.php (450)
2015/08/18 18:07:29 [trace] [system.db.CDbConnection] Starting transaction
in /Users/Sites/craft-test/web/craft/app/services/EntriesService.php (160)
in /Users/Sites/craft-test/web/craft/app/controllers/EntriesController.php (450)
in /Users/Sites/craft-test/web/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php (784)
2015/08/18 18:07:29 [trace] [system.CModule] Loading "elements" application component
in /Users/Sites/craft-test/web/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php (584)
in /Users/Sites/craft-test/web/craft/app/services/EntriesService.php (176)
in /Users/Sites/craft-test/web/craft/app/controllers/EntriesController.php (450)
2015/08/18 18:07:29 [warning] [application] Craft\ContentModel->title failed validation: Title cannot be blank.
in /Users/Sites/craft-test/web/craft/app/models/BaseModel.php (510)
in /Users/Sites/craft-test/web/craft/app/models/ContentModel.php (89)
in /Users/Sites/craft-test/web/craft/app/services/ContentService.php (218)
2015/08/18 18:07:29 [trace] [system.db.CDbTransaction] Rolling back transaction
in /Users/Sites/craft-test/web/craft/app/services/EntriesService.php (183)
in /Users/Sites/craft-test/web/craft/app/controllers/EntriesController.php (450)
in /Users/Sites/craft-test/web/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php (784)
```

This is on Craft Pro 2.4.2684 on Apache/2.4.10 (Unix) PHP/5.5.24.

I've tried clearing caches to no avail, and confirmed that the same issue exists with newly created Entry types with the Title field hidden.

Comment: In your entry type admin view, what do you have in the Title Format box?

Comment: That's the problem. I carried over the Twig syntax for the variable (`{{varName}}`) instead of the proper syntax (`{varName}`). Thank you!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out! Can you add that as an answer and close the question? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using the Twig template syntax (`{{varName}}`) in the Title Format field on the Entry Type instead of the proper syntax (`{varName}`).